# Tengo que hacer esto por cada query MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo que hacer esto cada vez que haga una consulta diferente por cada dato mostrado?

```
//Consultas
$results=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM tblusuarios");

print '<table border="1">';

while($row=$results->fetch_assoc()){
    print'<tr>';
    print'<td>'.$row['usuario'].'</td>';
    print '</tr>';
}
print '</table>';
```

Quiero decir, aquí solo muestra usuarios, pero hay alguna forma de que solo me muestre lo que pido en la consulta, es decir ahora pido todos los datos de cada row, que me  muestre solo lo seleccionado por el `SELECT`, o lo tengo que cambiar en el `$row`?

por ejemplo para las siguientes consultas:

```
 SELECT usuarios FROM `tblusuarios` ;

 SELECT MAX(saldo) FROM `tblusuarios` WHERE sexo='M';

 SELECT nombre, telefono from `tblusuarios` where marca='NOKIA'     OR
    marca='BLACKBERRY' OR marca='SONY';

 SELECT COUNT(ID)  FROM `tblusuarios` WHERE saldo=0 OR  activo=false;

 SELECT usuario FROM `tblusuarios` WHERE nivel=0 OR nivel=1 OR
    nivel=3;

 SELECT telefono FROM `tblusuarios` WHERE SALDO<= 300;  

 SELECT SUM(saldo) FROM `tblusuarios` WHERE compania='NEXTEL';
```

Tendría que hacer un `$row` con cada dato pedido en la consulta?, en caso de ser así cómo podría mostrar la `sum(saldo)` y similares totales?

Lo que pretendo hacer es una tabla para todas las consultas, a modo de gestor de base de datos pero en php

Comment: Podrías explicarte un poco mejor por favor, no logro entenderte del todo.

Comment: Lo que pretendo hacer es una tabla para todas las consultas, a modo de gestor de base de datos pero en php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu query puedes hacer cualquier consulta de cualquier tipo (como un buscador) y luego ejecutar ese query para que obtengas luego los resultados.

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE nombre LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY nombre", $link); 
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)){ 
  echo "<table border = '1'> \n"; 
  //Mostramos los nombres de las tablas 
  echo "<tr> \n"; 
while ($field = mysqli_fetch_field($result)){ 
        echo "<td>$field->name</td> \n"; 
} 
  echo "</tr> \n"; 
  do { 
        echo "<tr> \n"; 
        echo "<td>".$row["id"]."</td> \n"; 
        echo "<td>".$row["nombre"]."</td> \n"; 
        echo "<td>".$row["direccion"]."</td> \n"; 
        echo "<td>".$row["telefono"]."</td> \n"; 
        echo "<td><a href='mailto:".$row["email"]."'>".$row["email"]."</a></td> \n"; 
        echo "</tr> \n"; 
  } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)); 
        echo "</table> \n"; 
} else { 
   echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro !"; 
}
```

Todo depende a tu query que estas queriendo obtener

`$fila = mysqli_fetch_row(...)`, te devuelve un array con índices núméricos para los campos:
`$fila[0], $fila[1]`, etc...

`$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc(...)`, te devuelve un `array` asociativo (cadenas como índices) para los campos:
`$fila['campo_1'], $fila['campo_2']`, etc...

`$fila = mysqli_fetch_array(...)`, te devuelve un `array` con índices numéricos y asociativos. El tema de ahorrar recursos viene justamente porque esta función genera los dos arrays anteriores.
Mas información: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: me da un error >Call to undefined function mysql_query()

Comment: @kit desde PHP 7 las funciones mysql_* se declararon obsoletas y fueron removidas; esa puede ser la razón del mensaje

Comment: @kit ya actulice de mysql a mysqli

Answer (score 0):

puedes aplicarle un foreach a tu variable $row para obtener el valor y la clave

ejemplo:

```
    //Consultas
$results=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM tblusuarios");

print '<table border="1">';
$isHeader=1;
while($row=$results->fetch_assoc()){
    foreach ($row as $key=>$val){
      if($isHeader){//este opcion es para mostrar el nombre de los campos
        print'<tr>';
        print'<th>'.$val.'</th>';
        print '</tr>';
        $isHeader=0;
      }
      print'<tr>';
      print'<td>'.$val.'</td>';
      print '</tr>';

    }
}
print '</table>';
```

Comment: como podría ser cada nombre de columna con su campo? en plan tabla, así me sale todo en una tabla